# eval is evil, but is it flawed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, eval

If I run this:

```
eval('{ear: {"<=": 6}}');
```

I get an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Let's create the object manually:

```
var foo = {};
foo.ear = {};
foo.ear["<="] = 6;
```

Now, the following code:

```
JSON.stringify(foo)
```

Returns the following string:

> '{"ear":{"<=":6}}'

The same string as the one I started with (except the white characters, but those are irrelevant), so `eval(JSON.stringify(foo))` returns the same syntax error error message. However:

```
$.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(foo))
```

is executed correctly. What is the reason of that?

EDIT:

As nnnnnn and Ron Dadon pointed out, the initial string and the result of `stringify` are different. However, as I pointed out in the question, even the result of `stringify` used as input for `eval` will result in the syntax error message.

EDIT2:

Based on the answers and experiments conducted, this function is interesting:

```
function evalJSON(text) {
    return eval("(" + text + ")");
}
```

Comment: JSON.stringify does *not* return the same string as your first line. (Your first line isn't valid JSON because the first key name isn't quoted.) Have you tried assigning the result of your first line to a variable? `var x = eval(...)`

Comment: That's because `eval` tries to use an instruction block. You are not defining an object. Either that or nnnnn is right.

Comment: It is not the same - notice the quotes around "ear" in the JSON.stringify

Comment: I think you are confused what `eval()` does. It tries to create Javascript blocks, not JSON. Something like `eval('{var ear ={"<=":6}}');` works.

Comment: No need for `eval`. Drop `{ear: {"<=": 6}}` into your JS source code or the debug console, and you will also get a syntax error.

Comment: P.S. eval isn't evil; it's just a tool. Almost always the wrong tool, but not evil.

Comment: @nnnnnn, thanks for pointing out the difference. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Bonus points if you can figure out why the following variation does *not* give an error: `eval('{ear: {nose: 6}}')` (Let me know if you want a hint.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Is that related to my old favourite `onclick="javascript:alert(1)"` ?

Comment: @nnnnnn That's just a labeled block with a labeled int, inside a block.

Comment: @nnnnnn, the reason is that a code block just inside () is invalid, therefore the language supposes that the {} is actually for objects. At least this is how I understood.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Main `{}` are parsed as [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

try to wrap in parenthesis:

```
eval('({ear: {"<=": 6}})');
```

In javascript `{}` can be parsed as a block or an object

examples:

```
//object
var user = {
  name: "John",
  age: "32"
};

//block
{
   let a = 5;
   console.log(a);   
}

//object:
var a = {};
console.log({});
return {};
({});

//block:
function(){}
for(k in o){}
{}
```

Comment: Very interesting. Can you tell me why is the main {} parsed as block scope? Why is it parsed as object inside paranthesis? Are you suggesting this is a generally usable hack with the operators?

Comment: For the same reason, you need to wrap these self-invoking anonymous functions in parentheses as well.

Comment: @Thilo, is my comment right? If my comment right, then your answer is surely correct. If not, can you explain me why am I wrong in my comment?

Answer (score 7):

It's not flawed. To understand what is happening you need to understand what kind of statements are seen (left to right) by the parser.

A simple way to get into it is to play around with a [Javascript AST Visualizer](http://jointjs.com/demos/javascript-ast)

---

1. You will get the same exception with much simpler `{"b":4}`. It's parsed as  `"b":4` inside a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). That's not valid javascript. No AST tree for you...
   However it's due to an exception inside of a `{}` statement. That's a `BlockStatement`. AST tree: [image: AST tree for {}]
2. A similar `{b:4}` would be understood as `b:4`, a valid js statement - a `b` [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) for `4`... That's parsed as [image: AST tree for {b:4}]
3. Lastly, a `({b:4})` would be understood as an object declaration with a `b` property equal to `4`. That's parsed as [image: AST tree for ({b:4})]

---

**ECMAScript 2015**

On [Blocks](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-block):

> Block : { StatementList }

On [eval](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-performeval) itself:
Eval creates a new `Realm`, which is parsed (several steps here) as a sequence of `Statement`s ( a `StatementList` ), which in turn [this section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations) has `BlockStatement` as a first option. This **must** start with `{` (see above), so if you wrap it with a bracket (`({})`) it **cannot** be a `BlockStatement`... But if it matches as `BlockStatement` it **must** be a `BlockStatement`.

A side note in section on [Expressions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-expression-statement):

> An ExpressionStatement cannot start with a U+007B (LEFT CURLY BRACKET) because that might make it ambiguous with a Block

Comment: Are you sure? `eval('{b:4}')` returns 4.

Comment: That's because 'b:' is a lable. The block evaluates to the value of the last expression which is 4.

Comment: about labels: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/label

Answer (score 7):

Object literal notations need to be evaluated. This happens when you assign a variable:

```
var a = {ear: {"<=": 6}};
```

or when you put parentheses around it, a anonymous object:

```
({ear: {"<=": 6}});
```

Otherwise curly brackets are parsed as block markers. In your case this means `{ear:...}` is a label definition, the label is named ear. The next block `{"<=": 6}` gives you a syntax error because `"<=": 6` is invalid syntax.

The same applies if you put this into an `eval` statement.